# Function does not return the index while taking input from user

Tags: python

Function should return index to the any valid peak element, but does not return the index while taking an input from the user.

```
class Solution:   
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
    def peakElement(self):
         max=self.arr[0]
         for x in self.arr:
             if x>max:
                 max=x
                
         return self.arr.index(max)        
            
p=Solution(list(input()))
print(p.peakElement())
```

Comment: `list(input())` turns the user input into a list of 1 character strings. I suspect you want numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

You could traverse the list and filter out every element, where the value is equal to the `max()`. `self.arr.index(max)` will only return the first index.

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

    def peakElement(self):
        maximum = max(self.arr)
        return [i for i, j in enumerate(self.arr) if j == maximum]


p = Solution(list(input()))
print(p.peakElement())
```

**Input / Output:**

```
['5', '6', '5', '6']
[1, 3]
```